# How to know if NSURLSessionConfiguration is a backgroundSessionConfiguration?

Tags: ios

If the user provides it's own NSURLSessionConfiguration, how do I know if I can ask for a NSURLSessionDownloadTask or NSURLSessionDataTask since a NSURLSessionDataTask can't be created for a background session

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can decide weather the provided `NSURLSessionConfiguration` object is a background session or not by using its `identifier` property as

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = inConfig;

if(config.identifier != nil) {
     //Background session configuration
 }
 else {
     // not a Background session configuration
 }
```